# Oracle DataModeler Export DDL only for DB2 not works with Oracle Databases

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have designed my database with the DataModeler. 
Before that I versioning my schema I could export the schema to DDL Oracle 12 Database.

But since I have versionning with Subversion I can only export to DB2 databases (screenshot is following) :

[image]

When I click on Tools -> RDBMS Site Editor I don't see Oracle :

[image]

If I add a RDBMS Oracle Database 12c the export is the DB2 export and it return several errors.

I want to export the DDL statement for an Oracle Database, do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found thanks to Oracle Community. We must to :

1. Delete the folder C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler
2. Download and unzip a new data modeler and start with this new dataModeler.

Special thanks to Philip Stoyanov who very helps me ([Discussion Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/message/12629531)).